# lodash map returning array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

i have a arrray of objects where i wish to convert the data from medicine to type string. The only problem is instead of returning the array of objects is returing me the array of medicine.

Example
input:

```
data = [{medicine: 1234, info: "blabla"},{medicine: 9585, info: "blabla"},..]
```

desired output:

```
data = [{medicine: "1234", info: "blabla"},{medicine: "9585", info: "blabla"},..]
```

What im getting?
Array of medicine numbers.

Here is my code:

```
var dataMedicines = _.map(data, 'medicine').map(function(x) {
                return typeof x == 'number' ? String(x) : x;
            });
```

Comment: Well, your first `_.map(data, 'medicine')` strips out and return the medicine number into the next mapping function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lodash is much powerful, but for simplicity, check this demo

```js
var data = [{
  medicine: 1234,
  info: "blabla"
}, {
  medicine: 9585,
  info: "blabla"
}];

dataMedicines = _.map(data, function(x) {
  return _.assign(x, {
    medicine: x.medicine.toString()
  });
});

console.log(dataMedicines);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: is there a way to only have return object with medicine in it that's it, so it would look like 
[ {medicine: blabla} , {midicine: twoblacla} ]

Answer (score 8):

Or just a native ES6 solution:

```
const dataMedicines = data.map(({medicine, info}) => ({medicine: `${medicine}`, info}));
```

The advantage is that this is a more functional solution that leaves the original data intact.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want "transform" all medicine number to strings?

If that's the case, you don't need to first map.

```
var dataMedicines = _.map(data, function(x){
    var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)); // Create a copy so you don't mutate the original.
    newObj.medicine = newObj.medicine.toString(); // Convert medicine to string.
    return newObj;
});
```